# How to develop a .net Facebook application using Facebook .Net API?

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to start developing Facebook .Net desktop programs but I can't find any starter example for it. Only ASP.net and other web resources.

Anyone knows where can I find an example? can send one to me? (Just a "Hello World" post or something).

Please don't answear with link to codeplex resources of the FB.Net API. I searched the documentation and did find how to start from it.

Comment: From the "Related" section to the right on this page: [How can I use the Facebook C# SDK to post on Facebook Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361561/how-can-i-use-the-facebook-c-sdk-to-post-on-facebook-pages), [Facebook C# SDK Sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596890/facebook-c-sdk-sample-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for: [Creating a simple Facebook Application using WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFacebook.aspx)

It is from *CodePlex*, but has a real application sample, not an API description.

Comment: It says that after downloading the API I should have a file called Facebook.Controls.dll. Which I don't.

Comment: @Gal: Facebook.Controls is part of the Facebook SDK Binaries which the article instructs you to [download](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @Fredrik: The binaries only include Facebook.dll and Facbook.Contracts.dll

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CCD46762-45EC-4FBE-AD91-FC916671E734&displaylang=en

Comment: @Gal: odd, the source code seemed to contain the controls stuff.

Comment: Don't use that microsoft download to the facebook developer toolkit.  That toolkit has been abandoned and will only lead to frustration.