# What is the current status of Facebook's .Net SDK?

Tags: .net, facebook, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

So I need to do some API interaction with Facebook from .NET, i want to know how is this being handled nowadays. 
The [SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk) has been recommended a few times, but any sort of information seems to indicate that there is no one doing anything with that project, like the [website](http://facebooksdk.net/) is dead, and last Facebook and twitter updates are from 2015.

I just wanted to see if this is still the way to go, or if I should just ditch it and look somewhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: Nothing, the site is still down. For what I need, I will maybe not use it because i don't need a lot of the features, just a couple api calls, unless I heard something new about this in the next days.